# Ruby on Rails for developing Real Time Application? or Node.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js, rest

Can Ruby on Rails be used for developing Real Time Application (similar to like Facebook, twitter, geekList ) ? What sort of database (NoSql), REST API is required ? Node.js seems to be popular for RTA. Any insight will be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Would be good if you clarified more about the application.  Just saying, "Real Time Application" isn't very specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [Faye](http://railscasts.com/episodes/260-messaging-with-faye), but if you want development real time application, I think Node.js is the best. :)...Sorry, I'm only beginner developer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby and Rails can definitely be used for that (twitter was originally a Rails app).  What kind of db you need will depend on the specifics of your application.  I am guessing from your question that you are a beginner. In that case, I would guess this is one of your first applications and you are trying to figure out which technology to you.  I suggest you pick whichever one you are most interested in.  You can do the kind of application you are talking about in most modern web frameworks.